# The revalidate feature in Next.js 13.4.5 is not working when deployed to Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel, next.js13

I have a live site with posts that revalidate to 86400 (one day), but the posts are not refreshing even after 3 days. The revalidate works if it was a lower number, say below 1000. What is the highest value of revalidate that has worked for you? Does my code have a problem?

Next.js - 13.4.5 (upgrded to latest hoping its a bug still not working)
Server - Vercel

```
async function getPost(slug) {
  const url = config.apiUrl;
  const apiKey = config.apiKey;
  const res = await fetch(`${url}/blog/post/${slug}?api_key=${apiKey}`, {
    next: { revalidate: 86400 },
  });
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch the data");
  }
  return await res.json();
}

export default async function BlogPage({ params }) {
  const slug = params.slug;
  const post = await getPost(slug);
  return (....  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Revalidate and cache are still broken on Next.js 13.
Useful issue:

- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49417
- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/53695

For now, I didn't find a solution, because if you downgrade you will find other bugs if you upgrade as well.

If you don't have a long payload request and response, with the last version of the next.js (13.5.1) you should be fine.
Otherwise, you can use the last version and disable the cache with:

> cache: 'no-store'

on your fetch requests.

I'm waiting for a new upgrade of next.js 13 with a fix for all of that because I need the cache, I need the revalidate, and I have big payloads.

About your specific question: for me, the revalidate is not working at all, but may in your case need to check if your API is using another fetch, because if you have a nested fetch, the revalidate time will be equal to the lower one.
Not sure if that will work across the API server function, works like that if you call more than one fetch by the same function like that:

```js
async function test(){ 
   await fetch('url1', {
    next: { revalidate: 86400 },
  })
  await fetch('url2', {
    next: { revalidate: 1000},
  }) 
}
```